# elfinder issue with dialog or tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs, elfinder

I'm having this issue when i include elfinder inside my dialog w/tabs. The footer part overlaps the actual height size but once I resize the navbar (red circle) it auto-resizes perfectly. Anyone know how to fix this?

my jquery elfinder config:

```
$('#filemanager').elfinder({
        url: '/php/connector.minimal.php',
        defaultView: 'list',
        resizable: false,
        height: 475
    });
```

It looks like this at first:
[image]

Then after I resize the navbar (red circle):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told to try trigger `resize` on tab open and that worked.

```
$('#filemanager').trigger('resize');
```